# How to Average Multiple Columns in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following objects: Products, Ratings, and Users. I am trying to filter and select a number of Products that the User owns (through a `has_many :through` relationship with UserProducts) and average a certain column the Ratings table that matches their User ID and the correct Product ID.

So, my function is something along these lines:

```
def find_rating(criteria)
  product = self.products.find(:all, :conditions => ["criteria = ?", criteria])
  rating = self.ratings.where("product_id = ?", product).average(:overall)
end
```

I think that I'm going about this the wrong way, because I'm trying to find a product_id by passing an entire array of data consisting of multiple products. But, I think of using a more traditional loop and that seems convoluted. Can someone point me in the right direction for solving this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `product` is a single entry, as it appears to be in your code, I would do this:

```
rating = self.products.find_by_criteria(criteria).ratings.average(:overall)
```

If it's an array of products, this method may help you: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/ClassMethods/find_each

Comment: Sorry for the late accept- they have that five minute wait on here and then I forget about it sometimes until the next time I login. But thank you! I'm using the find_each method!